# How to fix vagrant up error: missing argument?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I'm having issues starting vagrant, when typing `vagrant up`. I receive:

> There was an error while executing VBoxManage, a CLI used by Vagrant
>       for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
>
> Command: ["sharedfolder", "add", "6a1009af-c43b-4737-a25e-664602fbf401", "--name", "", "--hostpath", "/home/name/Documents/Laravel-projects"]
>
> Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Missing argument to '--name'

Comment: paste your `Vagrantfile` looks like an issue with the `synced_folder` , does `/home/name/Documents/Laravel-projects` exists and have read access ?